# Jqgrid how to load jqgrid at specific page

Tags: php, jqgrid

I want to load jqgrid at the specific page when the browser refreshes it will still showing current page not start from the first page. without using reloadGrid function of jqgrid.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct the requierment you can set the jqGrid parameter **page** in order to do what you want. Below is example code

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    ...
    page : sessionpage ? sessionpage : 1,
    ...
});
```

This way every time you reload the grid if the session page is set it will be set as initial page otherwise page 1 (default) will be used